# Task dialog button control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to add a task dialog-style button control to my .NET application (C#).  It is labeled "Custom Button" in the screenshot below.

[Task dialog showing desired button control http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Bb760441.taskdialog(en-us,VS.85).jpg](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Bb760441.taskdialog(en-us,VS.85).jpg)

What is the name of this control for .NET, or how can I get it in my .NET form?

I need compatibility with XP (and other non-Vista, non-7 OS's).

I do not need to create the entire dialog.  I just want the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called CommandLink and its available since Vista.
You can use the [`TaskDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760540(VS.85).aspx) API to recreate the sample image that you posted.

Under .NET you can use the [Vista Bridge project](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VistaBridge) which wraps Vista\Win7 specific APIs (Including `TaskDialog`) for .NET.

Comment: Will this give a fallback for XP machines?  I should have mentioned that in my question.

Comment: No, unfortunately, XP doesn't support task dialogs or command links.

Comment: Nope, Vista Only, I assume that because the image that you show is Vista Task dialog.