# What is this control called?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, windows-7, controls

What is the name of the control that is highlighted blue?

[image]

I want to make this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [deviantart.net](http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2011/115/9/3/93029b80c65d51fc3f4fe2349e488a55-d3eu2b3.png))</sub>

It would be helpful if you found some link to a library. I've searched using many different names (TaskButton/TaskPanel/StackPanel) but I'm really off.

Thanks.

**Please note that the second image is only a concept sketch, and that it's not a real application.**

Comment: IMPORTANT! The second image is a concept sketch - it's not a real application. I'm referring more to the Windows 7 network list.

Comment: ok.. u can do list like the second image in WPF

Comment: I don't think you can assume that all of windows is written in .Net but you certainly can make your own control in WPF to look like that, as others have idicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely a custom (user) control which has been created by composing a number of standard WPF controls. It could easily be constructed in WPF using a horizontal `StackPanel` with various `Image`, `TextBlock` and `Button` elements as its content

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe that the control you are pointing to is a .NET or WPF control. Most Windows 7 user interface elements are still native C/C++ resources.

That said, it is relatively easy to replicate that behavior using WPF 4.0, through a ListBox with a custom ItemTemplate. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937306) to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

It looks rather like a `CommandLink` control to me, something that first appeared in Vista. It's never been exposed as a control for use in Windows Forms or WPF, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621912/task-dialog-button-control) contains information on how to make it available for your own use:

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it is a WPF user control, created specifically for this application. It looks like it consists of a `Image`, some `TextBox` controls and a `Button` which in turn contains an `Image`.

Comment: maybe a ListView with custom content.

Comment: Yes, the user control I described is most likely used to display the data bound to the `ListView`.

Comment: So I'm guessing I have to learn how to create a custom ListView control?

Comment: No. Just a user control that can be used as a DataTemplate for the items in the default ListView

Comment: Guess I'll leave this open. Someone must have created this before/there must be a name for this if it's used BY DEFAULT in Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how that control is called but my bet it is it's a custom windows form control, here's a link to get you [started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289517%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Most likely it is **not** Windows Forms but WPF.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. You can do this with the help of a simple button in WPF.
You have to embed another button and those images to that button.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button Height="38" Margin="12,49,83,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Button>
        <Grid Height="32" Margin="113,48,80,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="13*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="19*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="16*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="43*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="12*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Margin="0,6,0,0" Name="button2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="35" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="2">Button</Button>
            <Button Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="17,6,3,0" Name="button3" Grid.Column="2">Button</Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: It's not a clickable button though.